# CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.codename1.ui.Display$EdtException

Tags: codenameone

I've just discovered a new bug in the app I'm developing.
In the Simulator, this bug causes the CPU working at 100% for a while, producing a very long log (it seems a loop of something).
Finally, the log ends with:

```
CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.codename1.ui.Display$EdtException
```

It's the first time that I read `CIRCULAR REFERENCE` in a log. Is a circular reference a problem?

Comment: The log seems infinite (it's longer that 200000 lines), however it seems to repeat the same error. I reported the last lines of the log here: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/5acb57269f06671cdf93899546a3bfad At the moment, I'm not able to identify the code that reproduces the bug, that seems to happen in an unpredictable way. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is it possibly because of `setEnableAsyncStackTraces(true)`?

Comment: Maybe... yes. Can you please add some explanation? Do you mean that `setEnableAsyncStackTraces(true)` can be the cause of this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is triggered by a bug in `setEnableAsyncStackTraces(true)` which is fixed by this commit: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/ace2c4de8828cf3d2816cd3a58a889e56726a39d